# Kafka Streams performance with 1 key or multiple key

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

I am using 1.5.4 spring boot, java 8 and kafka 2.2.0 version. I have 5 broker and 4 different topics with each 50 partitions.

I have a system like this:

I have 2 or 3 million of records. I am exporting those records by 2500, 2500 parts on each kafka message. I mean 1 kafka message consists of 2500 records, but I am using SAME key, that means all of those records go to same partition. I am using compacted topic that have also 2-3 milliyon of records and I am using ktable - kstream join and gather another record. (This records have different key like Id, in order to repartitioning) After this join operation I am back to my original key do the repartition. My kafka streams code that listens this topic and do repartition and join operations like 3 times repartition and 2 times join operation, but like I said all of these topic messages use same key after above operation. My spring-boot application consists of 10 concurreny for each application and I have 5 replicas of my spring boot application.

Sum up : 5 broker + 4 different topics + internal topics but all of my operation uses same key which means all messages go to always 1 partition.

Let's say I am using key as A

My question is, if I distribute my messages with different keys to different partitions (now I have key A1,A2,A3,A4...A50) can I get good performance ? What are the cons and pros of it? I mean if I use 1 partition, does kafka use less disk operations on a server machine and less network cost? Because my join operations go on the same partition ? Does kafka reach & read messages faster on join operations with 1 partition ? Becase it can differ from distributing messages to 50 partitions and may be it would be a hard to read from different partitions, different machine and different partition. I should think that different partitions could be on other server I mean other broker? Would that be a network cost?

Because of using same key all my messages on internal topics go the same partition right? And only 1 thread can consume from that partition

If I distribute to 50 partitions I would do the batch job as 50 and distribute to 50 partition, does my code performance increase like x2 x3 x4 times ? Can I get idea please

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, if I distribute my messages with different keys to
>   different partitions (now I have key A1,A2,A3,A4...A50) can I get good
>   performance ?

increasing partitions gives u increase in performance. generally a msg of 800bytes, single partition gives u 24k msgs/sec. if u have 2 parttions this will become 48k msgs/sec

> What are the cons and pros of it? I mean if I use 1 partition, does
>   kafka use less disk operations on a server machine and less network
>   cost?

The only cons is that u lose sequencing btw the msgs across partitions.

> Because my join operations go on the same partition ? Does kafka reach
>   & read messages faster on join operations with 1 partition ?

kafka consumer reads each of the partitions in parallel. meaning there can be a consumer on jvm1 consuming partition1; while consumer 2 on jvm 2 consuming partition 2 in paralell. Added, consumer 1 and consumer 2 need not consume at the same speed.